# What happened to my iChat account?

Tags: messages, ichat

Having recently upgraded my machine to Mountain Lion, I realized that there is no iChat app anymore and that everything ended up into the Messages app. I've been using a `@mac.com` account specifically to access iChat, so what happens to this account now? Has it become useless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing changes for accessing AIM chat using the new Messages app (that integrates iChat features with iMessage features).

Just go to Messages -> Preferences -> Accounts to be sure your @mac.com account is entered with a password and enabled for use.

Comment: Should I set it up as a new AIM account?

Comment: It's not a new account, but you need to sign in if the app doesn't have your AIM information entered/configured. So yes - make a new account on the app, but don't tell the app to get a new AIM account from AIM for you.